# Craft 3 – Render template as if it were a site request

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I have a Craft 3 plugin that renders a portion of an entry after save in order to index the resulting information. The plugin needs full access to the Twig extensions on the site to render the template, however several plugins that add such extensions check:

`if( Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsSiteRequest() )`

As a result not all Twig extensions load when `renderTemplate` is called from the control panel. I set the template mode using:

`Craft::$app->getView()->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE)`

but that only updates the path to the template. Is it possible to render the template as if it were a site request?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect not without manually manipulating the path before the Request class is initialised.

One possible alternative solution would be to use Guzzle to call the front-end URL rather than the CP URL, which will render the template with `getIsSiteRequest` set to `true`, for example:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('get', 'http://url/front-end-template');
$body = $response->getBody();
```

It would also be possible to create your own controller which fetches the template and to hit it with a front-end action request:

```
$response = $client->request('get', 'http://url/actions/plugin/controller/action');
```

Comment: How should this enable one to manipulate the `getIsSiteRequest` to become true? The variable is set during the initialization of the component `craft\web\Request` and it checks the current URL segments for certain strings once. After that it returns always the same value no matter what. The only way I found is to change the classloader in order to load a custom `Request` class

Comment: By hitting the front-end URL instead of a CP URL, `getIsSiteRequest` will automatically be set to true.

Comment: Ahh alright I missunderstood you. I thought you wanted to hit the request in order to change it on global level.. Of course you are totally right. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I realise it's not ideal but I can't think of a way around it right now.

Comment: I added a second option to my answer which might be cleaner.

Comment: Apologies for the slow response, I wanted to wait until I'd dug into it a bit further before responding. I had a go at using Guzzle for the task last week. While it works for many cases, I ran into a few issues. It seems that in EVENT_AFTER_SAVE an entry that has just been published or enabled isn't actually enabled yet, so it returns a 404. I investigated using temporary tokens, but that doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Comment: Strange, I would expect the entry to be enabled by the time EVENT_AFTER_SAVE is triggered...